# Google Smart Home custom devices and sensors

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

Is there any way to use the Google Smart Home actions platform for custom devices that are not supported like let's say a motion sensor? If not is there any way we can create custom actions and make it work together with Smart Home platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ["types"](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/) of devices are somewhat trivial to support or not support. They're really useful semantically, when the user is referring to a set of devices (like lights). What is more important are the [traits](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/), which represent the capabilities of devices.

For a motion sensor, you can register it as any device type (such as a Light). While that may not make a lot of sense, it'd work. You would then want to take a look at the traits for what capabilities make sense.

Consulting the list, you may or may not find one that fits. If you need custom capabilities, you should take a look at building a [conversational Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/) which provides greater flexibility.

Comment: Can we integrate or run both the smart home actions and conversational actions together?
Sry I am very new to all of this

Comment: One more question can you suggest traits that can be suitable for controlling a speaker? Playing music on it?

Comment: No, you cannot have an Action that is both part of smart home and conversational. You would need to build two separate projects. For a speaker, there are no traits for media initiation or playback control.

Comment: @NickFelker Google smart home certification team does not approve the action if the device type does not match the product in the market. Also, the conversational action sunset is scheduled in June 2023. So now the only option to support custom devices is to raise the issue on issuetracker ?